# Creating JList from HashMap

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jlist

I'm building a booking system for a pretend Gym, I've got a class for Customers, one for Gym Sessions, and a Session Manager that collects the Sessions together into a `HashMap`.

Each Session has a hash map to collect the customers booked on. I have a master class with a GUI to perform assorted functions. I would like to be able to open a new `JPanel`/`JFrame` containing a `Jlist`, that when a particular session is selected, it displays the customers which are booked on to it, however I've been unable to find the relevant methods to do so.

Relevant code below:

Customer Class

```
public class Customer {

private final String name;
private final String payMethod;
public final UUID uniqueId;

/*
* Constructor for me.davehargest.weekendfitness.customer.struct.Customer
*
* @param String name    The customers name
* @param int id         The sequential ID Reference of the customer
*/
public Customer(String name, UUID uniqueId, String payMethod) {
    this.name = name;
            this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    this.payMethod = payMethod;
}
}
```

Session Class

```
public class Session {

private int sessionId;
private String sessionName;
    private double price; // Cost of the session per Person
    private double totalEarnings; // Total Earnings of the Session (Number of People * @price
    private Date sessionDate; //Date that the session takes place
    private int classNumber = 1;
/*
* Generates a HashMap of the Customers that will be booked onto a class    
*/   
public Map <Integer, Customer> customers = new HashMap <>();

 /**
 * Session Constructor
 * Creates a new instance of a session
 * 
 * @param sessionId - An identification ID for the Exercise Session
 * @param sessionName - A description of the actual exercise i.e. "Yoga"
 * @param price - The cost to attend the session per person
 * @param sessionDate
 */

public Session(int sessionId, String sessionName, double price, Date sessionDate) 
{
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
this.sessionName = sessionName;
    this.price = price;
    this.sessionDate = sessionDate;
    totalEarnings = 0;
}

/*
* Method addCustomer
* 
* @param Customer - Adds a new Customer to the Exercise Session 
*/

public void addCustomer (Customer customer)
{
    if (customers.size() >= 20){
        System.out.println("Class is full");
    } else {
            customers.put(classNumber, customer); // Adds in a new Customer to the session ArrayList
            totalEarnings += price; // Adds the per person cost to total fees
            classNumber++;
            System.out.println("Added: " + classNumber + customer);
    }
}
```

SessionManager Class

```
public class SessionManager {

    /*
    * A HashMap of all of the different Sessions that WeekEnd Fitness Offers
    */
    public Map<Integer, Session> sessions = new HashMap<>();

    private int sId = 1;

    public SessionManager() {}

    public void addSession(String sessionName, double price, String seshDate) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        sessionDate = format.parse(seshDate);
        this.sessions.put(this.sId, new Session(sId, sessionName, price, sessionDate));
        sId ++;
    }
 }
```

I'm sure this is really simple stuff, but it's seemingly beyond my comprehension at the moment, any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated, thank-you!

Comment: try editing title to describe what ur trying to do, such as 'create jframe from hashmap' or something and include jframe in tags u might have better luck getting answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - Wen asking for GUI related stuff shouldnt you show your GUI code?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `JList` from the `HashMap` like I've shown in below example.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Vector;

public class CustomerList {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Sample data
    Map<Integer, Customer> customers = new HashMap<>();
    customers.put(1, new Customer("Kevin", UUID.randomUUID(), "Cash"));
    customers.put(2, new Customer("Sally", UUID.randomUUID(), "Credit card"));
    customers.put(3, new Customer("Kate", UUID.randomUUID(), "Cash"));

    Vector<ListItem> items = new Vector<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Customer> entry : customers.entrySet()) {
      items.add(new ListItem(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

    JList list = new JList(items);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Customer List");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class ListItem {
  private int classNumber;
  private Customer customer;

  ListItem(int classNumber, Customer customer) {
    this.classNumber = classNumber;
    this.customer = customer;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    // You can change this to suite the presentation of a list item
    return classNumber + " - " + customer.name + " (" + customer.payMethod + ")";
  }
}

class Customer {

  final String name;
  final String payMethod;
  public final UUID uniqueId;

  public Customer(String name, UUID uniqueId, String payMethod) {
    this.name = name;
    this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    this.payMethod = payMethod;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you! Yes this worked exactly as I needed, thank-you very much, I've been scratching my head for days trying to get this to work.

Comment: Sorry to extend to this, I can't seem to get a Listener Event to work for this, I thought it was supposed to be along the lines of this code:


ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent) {

Session session = new Session(this.currentSessions.getSelectedValue());

But it keeps telling me it cannot find variable currentSessions?

Comment: @2PintsofTea, in this code segment, you are writing an anonymous inner class of type `ListSelectionListener`. Inside that inner class, `this` means that inner class instance. So, may be you can try something like `<ParentClass>.this.currentSessions` (or you can simply use `currentSessions` without "this." as well.).

Comment: sorry one last query, that's working in pulling the right information to System.out.println, now I'd like to take the object selected in the list, and add it into other Hashmaps etc. So I've got Customer cust = (Customer) currentCustomers.getSelectedValue(); which as far as I can tell should work, but I'm getting the ClassCast error, where it says my List cannot be case to the object class, the list class is what I've used to populate the JList as per your first answer. Do I have to do some form of conversion, or retrieval of the actual object that is selected? etc?

Comment: In my answer, I've used `ListItem` objects to create the `JList`. So, if I call `list.getSelectedValue()` it will return an object of type `ListItem`. So, I cannot cast it to a `Customer` object. (Since I don't see your code, I'm answering based on few assumptions. So, if this doesn't work, may be you can post another question with details and code of your current problem.)